# How to deal with the grudged HR manager?

Tags: career-development, hiring-process, human-resources

I just have started a new position. Prior to it, during the interviews, HR had tried to offer a lower salary than I was willing to accept. Although I had been told by the HR that they could not offer the figure i was asking for (and been told "best of luck"), one week later hiring manager called me, and accepted my offer.

Yesterday, i saw the HR manager on my way out from the office and tried to say hi, but she gave me a really really cold hi.

I believe she resents that i got the job out of their planned offer scale. How can i deal out with the situation, immediately, so that my career progress not likely to be hindered?

Comment: Gosh, you're reading a lot into a one word comment. Maybe she was just having a bad day?

Comment: @PhilipKendall that also a possibility, but i have to be ready for the worst case.

Comment: A real cold hi? Did you start freezing? As Philip Kendall said, don't jump to conclusions. _If_ you jump to conclusions, don't tell anyone at the company.

Comment: @gnasher729 as i replied to PK, i have to be ready for the worst case.

Comment: You can't go through life assuming the worst case all the time, because then you never get anything useful done. What are you going to do if the HR manager is conspiring with your best friend to frame you for murder?

Comment: At the end of the day it's probably your manager who decides when you get raises or promotions, right?  Being on the bad side of HR might suck for a lot of reasons, but it shouldn't hinder your *career.*  Besides which, even if you're right, she can't stay mad forever.  Just be nice to her and don't give her any *new* reasons to hate you, and sooner or later she'll get over it.

Comment: Simply (1) be extremely polite and (2) totally separate your "work life" from personal emotions.  Do not "think" about this person ever - be 100% professional and get on with your job.  if you have to interact with the person in any way, follow point (1).

Comment: @gnasher729 I ask the moderators to delete this comment. You are consistently trying to spam this question area. While I don't care about that, you should leave my family out of the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the short term do a great job and show to everyone that you are worth every penny (or local equivalent) they are paying you.

After you have demonstrated your worth and you have been there a while talk to your manager about whether a change of tile or level would be appropriate. This could put you in a salary range which doesn’t break HR’s guidelines. This may require you to take on more and/or different responsibilties.

Answer (score 7):

You have been hired. HR will most likely not have much say in your life unless unusual things happen. So do your jop, stay clear of trouble, and you can smile on her every day.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an observation that I have often made: People try unconsciously to meet your expectations. Once you realise that, you adjust your expectations to be more positive, and your experience with these people will improve.

If you expect the worst from this HR person ("I have to be ready for the worst case"), they will tend to meet your expectations, and the worst will happen. If you think the best of that person, chances are they will unconsciously try to meet your expectations, and all goes well. Without realising what is happening, that person will feel what you think about them, and tend to act accordingly, without even knowing it.